# How can I get excellent answers from a very general/high level question

Tags: discussion

I admire some users that ask a very general question but get excellent answers. Such as this question: [What is meant by a “random variable”?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-is-meant-by-a-random-variable/54894#54894) I am talking about the long answer for this question by @whuber.

I personally think this is not a good question, because too general. If I am asking it, probability will be close by **too broad** or get some answer like **go to read a book**.

But why such question exist and can get good answers? How can I do that? I am assuming this is not repeatable because it is randomly selected by some high reputation users?

Comment: That's an excellent question.

Comment: Part of the reason might be that this particular question is from 2010... The customs have changed a bit since then.

Comment: I personally wonder if we have moved a little too far in ruling out general / high level questions (cf, [Are we closing questions too fast?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/3119/7290)). There are undoubtedly questions that are too broad, but there can be questions that are broad but nonetheless valuable.

Comment: To motivate the discussion here, it might help to give an example or two of general questions you would like to ask.

Comment: It seems to me that questions concerning basic concepts in statistics *have* to be considered on topic.  What's "too broad" about asking for a definition, explanation, or examples of a random variable (or a PDF, or a statistic, or a probability space, or expectation, ... etc.)?

Comment: @whuber Well, `What do they mean when they say "random variable"?` (being the entire question) might not be too broad, but exhibits some glaring lack of research, which is one of the officially recommended reasons for downvoting.

Comment: Sometimes it's luck - a less inspiring question will happen to get a good answer. Sometimes the question is better than it might first seem, especially if it asks something fundamental in a way that gives an opening for a good exposition on the matter.

Comment: @gung I made another attempt here, see if I can get good answer. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224005/why-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-spd-is-so-important

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By explaining what more you're looking for than you'd get from reading the relevant Wikipedia article, a textbook, or whatever a couple of minutes' Googling turns up. Bringing up some point of confusion or a difficulty in application presents people with a fun challenge (whether that's to explain something, or to work it out for themselves & then explain it) rather than a boring request for information readily available elsewhere.

Of course questions that come down to "explain $X$ to me" sometimes get very good, original, answers—like @Glen_b I think that's just luck.